# Is Content of Word Content Control changeable without developer mode on?

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I'm changing content of content control with c# OPENXML SDK.Sometimes customer wants to change content of content control when they open the word document. I didn't find any way to change it without developer mode.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

The way I did this is when the final document is ready, I went ahead and removed the content control from the document. That way, the text now becomes editable.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the text ***is*** editable.  If its not, check your [lock settings](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/lock.html).

Comment: actually it is not editable. but i couldnt find and i change my coding style.  Thank you.